# Special layout with jumping floats in Foundation 4 (pics inside)

Tags: css, mobile, css-float, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

at the moment i am developing a new page for a client in Foundation 4 (ZURB). There is a mobile and a desktop version. Of course both have the same HTML, only the CSS changes depending on the breakpoints.
Now comes the complicated part:

[Desktop version](http://www.dyschelmann.com/dump/bsp1.png)

[Mobile version](http://www.dyschelmann.com/dump/bsp2.png)

How can I achieve that the menu jumps to the very bottom of the content?
Here is a simplified version of the HTML structure.
Any thoughts on how to achieve this with pure css / specific Foundation classes?
At the moment I am working with duplicate content like so:

```
<section class="large-16 push-8 columns">Article Section 1</section>
<nav class="large-8 pull-16 columns hide-for-small"><!-- my menu -->
<aside class="large-8 pull-16 columns">Image 1</aside>

<section class="large-16 push-8 columns">Article Section 2</section>
<aside class="large-8 pull-16 columns">Image 2</aside>
<nav class="column hide-for-large"><!-- same menu as above -->
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I need the top edge of each image to align with the top edge of the corresponding section on desktop. Probably there is no sollution without the use of duplicate content or JS.

Comment: are you only concerned about the menu going to the side or do you also need the images to go to the side as well?

Comment: The second it is. Also I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not ideal to still use multiple elements but here is how you can make the menu change positions.  I still had to use the show-for-small and hide-for-small on the images though because of their positioning differences.

CSS

```
 @media only screen and (min-width:768px){
    .menuNav{
       float:left;
    }
    .contentDiv{
       float:right;
    }
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="contentDiv large-8 small-12 columns"> 
    <section class="articleSection">
        <p>Article Section 1</p>
    </section>
    <aside class="img show-for-small">Image 1</aside>
    <section class="articleSection">
        <p>Article Section 2</p>
    </section>
    <aside class="img show-for-small">Image 2</aside>
  </div>
  <div class="menuNav large-4 small-12 columns">
    <ul class="navDiv side-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <aside class="img hide-for-small">Image 1</aside>
    <aside class="img hide-for-small">Image 2</aside>
  </div>
```

JSBin example
http://jsbin.com/ovabel/5/edit

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the right answer. But I forgot to mention that I need the top edge of each image to align with the top edge of the corresponding section on desktop.

Comment: Fair enough. I will take a look at it this weekend if I find a chance.

Comment: Does that mean that you want the images on the right to be lower so they can line up, leaving whitespace where the menu is?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And if the menu is very high, the images should not overlap. Thank you for yor time :)